# Spacing of lines different in Internet Explorer than in Firefox

Tags: wordpress

I have a `Wordpress` website with a page that loads correctly in Firefox but not in Internet Explorer. The first image is as it is displayed in Internet Explorer (with the lines too spaced out), the second Firefox (as I would like it displayed). I cannot see why they should be different. Can anyone suggest why this is happening? I am using the Weaver theme.

**Internet Explorer**

[image]

**Firefox**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A month has gone by so hopefully you have found your answer (do share).  In my experience with Firefox vs Explorer, I found Firefox to be more forgiving and Explorer to be more sensitive about nesting closures.  Explorer requires them to be Exactly correct.  Attributes Must be ended in the correct order (i.e. backing out).  Also a missing div or p closure may pass in Firefox but not Explorer.

You are probably more experienced than I (most are!) so your problem may be more advanced!  However, I found my solution with a cut-paste to a Word document. Then aligned all beginnings and endings with line returns as needed, indenting for clarity.  Even some bold and/or coloring.  Clip most content to focus on the nesting. Bingo. Then go back to WP and fix.

I expect third-party code editors to be more efficient in error trapping, that will be my next learning.